# How to export file with headers in Google Dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to export the results of a Google Dataprep job.  As you can see in the following screenshot, the columns have names or headers:

[image]

However, the exported file is not including them. How can I keep those column headers in the exported CSV file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the "Run Job on Dataflow" dialog, you can configure the output to be a single CSV file with headers. You need to click on the pencil to edit an output target, and then enable single file output and including headers under "More options" for the CSV output.

This is how the ouput target should look like afterwards:

[image: Click edit here]

The option for including headers is under "More Options":

[image: Options]

Comment: Thanks for your help.